# How to check in PHP whether page is directly loaded or being redirected from other page?

Tags: php, redirect, pageload

Suppose I am having two pages Page1.php and Page2.php. Sometimes Page1.php is directly loaded and sometimes it is being redirected from Page2.php. My question is that can I check whether Page1.php is directly loaded or it's being redirected from the Page2.php.(if query string is not used)

Comment: What are you trying to do / why do you want this? Maybe there is another solution.

Comment: This is because I am having login.php page and validation.php page.In validation page username and password is matched with the database value and if not it redirects to login.php page. So on redirection I need to show some error message in the login page and if not I dont need.

Answer (score 7):

Set a session variable in Page2.php and control for it in Page1.php

**Page2.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['from2'] = true;
header('Location: /Page1.php');
?>
```

**Page1.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['from2']) && $_SESSION['from2']) {
  /* from Page2.php logic here */

  unset($_SESSION['from2']);
}else{
  /* not from Page2.php */
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read the value of global variable `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`.

Comment: This may work if the need for correctness is low. The Referer field is optional in HTTP and some browsers don't send them (I've disabled it in my, and some firewalls removes it from requests).

Comment: I guess you can use this, but not for critical applications(not reliable), because the referrer can be spoofed. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referrer_spoofing. Then I think the answer from Emil using sessions is more secure.

Comment: Still this is the only sane way to do this if you are not passing any parameters in the URL. Of course you could also try storing cookies remembering the current page, but this also would be not 100% safe.

Answer (score 1):

$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']

Though check out the manual to see why it cannot be trusted:
https://www.php.net/manual/ro/reserved.variables.server.php